# sqlite3 - Exception: database disk image is malformed

Tags: sqlite, ironpython

i'm working with IronPython 2.6 for .Net4 and sqlite3 module from: [IronPython.SQLite](http://bitbucket.org/jdhardy/ironpython.sqlite/wiki/Home).

i have a written a GUI program what runs in four frames of an MDI window. Every of the four programs receives data from a serialport and stores this data in a sqlite database. One database per program.
Between inserting this data on receive into the database the program querys the database every 100ms for the latest data items.

I'm already using a mutex call for the cursor.execute() command to prevent problems with simultaneous commands (insert or select).

During runtime the program (sporadically) runs into an exception.

When trying to query data:

```
System.Exception: database disk image is malformed
```

or when trying to insert data:

```
System.Exception: database or disk is full
```

Is it possible, that an database query short after an database insert (or the way around) could cause such exceptions and destroy the database?

It would be very kind of you, if you could give me a kind of advice how to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm looking into this, but it might take me a day or two to get to it. Sorry.

Comment: I would bet it's an locking problem. could you check, if the database-file is locked, before inserting ? (I delved quite deep into C#-SQLite myself)